# How to find the rational representation of angle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, trigonometry

I am puzzled by this problem encountered. One angle of right triangle with sides 
         $ 3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2$
is

$$ \theta = \arccos(\frac{4}{5}) $$

$$ \exp(i\theta) = \frac{4}{5} + \frac{3}{5} i$$

and

$$\theta = \dfrac{2\pi r}{t} $$

where $r$ and $t$ most likely integers.

Is there a way for finding $r$ and $t$?

Comment: No body know the exact value of $\arccos(4/5)$. Of course it is of the form $2\pi x$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and it may be irrational

Comment: Not sure why this is the situation, I thought there must be some algorithm out there for find it.

Comment: If $\theta = \frac {2\pi r}{r}$ for some intergers $r,t $ then $(0.8 + 0.6i)^t = 1.$  The decimal expansion of $\Re(0.8 + 0.6i)^t$ and $\Im(0.8 + 0.6i)^t$ has $t$ digits.  $\theta$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi$

Comment: @wang1908 You may note that only the angles $0$, $\pi/6$ and $\pi/2$ have rational $\sin$.

Comment: If $e^{2\pi i r/t} = \frac{4}{5} + \frac{3}{5}i$, are we looking a  $\frac{4}{5} + \frac{3}{5}i$ is which $2t$-th root of $1$ ?

Answer (score 5):

If $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ are both rational then either $\tfrac{\theta}{2\pi}=\tfrac{n}{4}$ for some integer $n$ or $\tfrac{\theta}{2\pi}$ is transcendental.

$\tfrac{\theta}{2\pi}$ is either rational or irrational.

Suppose that $\tfrac{\theta}{2\pi}$ is rational. Then $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}$ is a [root of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity), so its minimal polynomial is a [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial). But $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}$ is also a [Gaussian rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_rational), so its minimal polynomial is of degree $1$ or $2$. The only cyclotomic polynomials of degree $1$ or $2$ are those corresponding to $1,2,3,4,6$, and of these only $1,2,4$ correspond to roots of unity where both the real and imaginary parts are rational. Hence $\tfrac{\theta}{2\pi}=\tfrac{n}{4}$ for some integer $n$.

Suppose $\tfrac{\theta}{2\pi}$ is irrational. If $\tfrac{\theta}{2\pi}$ were algebraic, then $\tfrac{2\theta}{\pi}$ would be irrational and algebraic. Since $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi/2}$ is algebraic, $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}=(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi/2})^{2\theta/\pi}$ would have to be transcendental, by the [Gelfond–Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem). But by hypothesis $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta}$ is algebraic, so $\tfrac{2\theta}{\pi}$ can't be algebraic. Therefore it must be transcendental, so $\tfrac{\theta}{2\pi}$ is also transcendental.

Comment: In the Gelfond–Schneider theorem, the hypothesis that the exponent be irrational cannot be removed. But I shoudn't have invoked the theorem on $\mathrm{e}^{2\pi \mathrm{i}}$, so I changed that (and made the proof of negation more apparent).

Comment: Yes.  Nailed it down now.

Answer (score 1):

$$\theta = arccos(\frac{4}{5}) = (0.204832765...)\pi $$

I do not think it is a rational multiple of  $\pi$

Comment: What about $0.20481927...=17/83$ or $0.20483314...=178/869$  Have to be rather careful about thinking all the rational numbers are easy to spot.

Comment: True. In the case of  $ arccos(\frac{4}{5})$,   we do not even know if it is rational multiple of $\pi$ or not. I don't think it is.